# Ruby return statement does not work with super keyword?

Tags: ruby

```
class Parent
  def test
    return
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def test
    super
    p "HOW IS THIS POSSIBLE?!"
  end
end

c = Child.new
c.test
```

I though that, since the `test` method from the `Parent` class immediately uses the return statement, it should not be possible to print the line of the `Child` class. But it is indeed printed. Why is that?

Ruby 1.8.7, Mac OSX.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`super` acts like a method call that calls the superclass's method implementation. In your example, the `return` keyword returns from `Parent::test` and continues executing `Child::test`, just like any other method call would.

Comment: Oh.. I see. But I wonder, how would I achieve the effect I was expecting?

Comment: @Omega Try `return super`.

Comment: Post a new question, and describe what you want to accomplish.

Comment: result = super; return result

Answer (score 14):

Another way to think of the call to `super` in this context is if it were any other method:

```
class Parent
  def foo
    return
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def test
    foo
    p "THIS SEEMS TOTALLY REASONABLE!"
  end
end

c = Child.new
c.test
# => "THIS SEEMS TOTALLY REASONABLE!"
```

If you really wanted to prevent the call to `p`, you need to use the return value from `super` in a conditional:

```
class Parent
  def test
    return
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def test
    p "THIS SEEMS TOTALLY REASONABLE!" if super
  end
end

c = Child.new
c.test
# => nil
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to work around it using yield and block.

```rb
class Parent
  def test
    return
    yield
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def test
    super do
      p "HOW IS THIS POSSIBLE?!"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a mater of ancestors order.

An other way to allow an early return from supercharged method would be to use module/concern implementation (instead of inheritance) and to prepend it (and not include).

```rb
class TestConcern
  def test
    return
    super # this line will never be executed
  end
end

class Child
  prepend TestConcern
  def test
    p "THIS LINE WILL NOT BE PRINTED... (but it's quite an obfuscated behaviour)"
  end
end
```

BTW, I find this obfuscate rather than simplify.

Answer (score 0):

You could use exceptions

```
class Parent
  class ReturnEvent < RuntimeError;end

  def test
    raise ReturnEvent
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def test
    super
    p "HOW IS THIS POSSIBLE?!"
    rescue ReturnEvent
  end
end

c = Child.new
c.test
```