# Timing for calling `super`

Tags: ruby

I should understand this piece of code:

```
module Stealth
  module MixpanelSessionTracking
    def set(flow:, state:)
      retval = super

      if ENV['MIXPANEL_PROJECT_TOKEN'].present?
        mixpanel = Stealth::Mixpanel.new
        mixpanel.tracker.track(user_id, 'State Change', {
          'flow' => flow,
          'state' => state
        })
      end

      retval
    end
  end

  class Session
    prepend Stealth::MixpanelSessionTracking
  end

end
```

Why do I set `super` to `setval` variable, and before I call `retval` variable at the end of the method definition?

Could I just use `super` at end of the method definition?

**EDIT:**

The antecessor class method:

```
module Stealth
  class Session
    (...)
    def set(flow:, state:)
      store_current_to_previous(flow: flow, state: state)

      @flow = nil
      @session = canonical_session_slug(flow: flow, state: state)

      Stealth::Logger.l(topic: "session", message: "User #{user_id}: setting session to #{flow}->#{state}")
      $redis.set(user_id, session)
    end
    (...)
  end
end
```

Comment: That depends on the code in between `retval = super` and `retval`. You have not provided that, so we cannot answer it.

Comment: @sawa you rewrote half of the post, but chose to highlight the "peace"? Why not just fix it? I don't understand.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I knew you were going to say that. :)

Comment: @sawa yeah, it's not the first time. :/

Comment: @sawa I edit the post with this information, sorry for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good decsribe what do `super` in ruby docs [there](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/ProgrammingRuby/book/tut_classes.html) and [answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519377/ruby-return-statement-does-not-work-with-super-keyword):

> super acts like a method call that calls the superclass's method implementation. In your example, the return keyword returns from Parent::test and continues executing Child::test, just like any other method call would.

In your case somebody just define `retval` as `super` and then in code use retval instead of super.

Comment: So, if I use `super` in last line of my method, this is works equal?

Comment: Yes. When you invoke super with no arguments, Ruby sends a message to the current object's parent, asking it to invoke a method of the same name as the current method, and passing it the parameters that were passed to the current method.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to see `ancestors` for your class it will be like [Stealth::MixpanelSessionTracking, Session] cause you use `prepend`.

Then you call `set` you first call Stealth::MixpanelSessionTracking and super inside `set` method from Session class because of ancestor chain with prepend.